# MYSQL search WHERE a value is in a json_encoded field

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in PHP/MYSQL to create a query to search directly inside an array json_encoded inside a field?

for example I have a table USERS:

```
|  ID   |   Name       |    ArrayPermissionsID    |
---------------------------------------------------
|   1   | John         | '{1,2,4,5}'              |
---------------------------------------------------
|   2   | Bob          | '{1,2,6,7,8,9}'          |
---------------------------------------------------
|   3   | Walter       | '{1,}'                   |
```

and `ArrayPermissionsID` is a field where I convert an array in PHP using `json_encode();`

Is there a query like? : `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE JSON_DECODE(ArrayPermissionsID) IN (?, ?, ?, ....)`

Comment: Your "JSON" is invalid, using JSON functions would be useless.

Comment: Create a table `permissionsIds` related to `ID users` to keep the BD correctly structured